# ios custom delegate setup

Tags: ios, delegates, protocols

I am trying to make a custom protocol that i hope somebody might help with.

I have a mainViewController (mainVC) that has a label. That label needs to be updated with a string when i press a button in edwwVC.

I am using ARC and storyboard.

The problem is when i press the Done Button on the edwwVC, the "done" method is called BUT the delegate method is not called in mainVC.
Whereas, if i call the done method VIA the mainVC, then the done method is called AND the delegate method. So I can see the connection is there, I just do not understand why the delegate method is not called when i press the done button in the edwwVC.

I imagine it has something to do with the init of the edwwVC. Because it is already initiated by storyboard, so it looks to me as if I am initializing it again the in the viewDidLoad method of the mainVC. But that is how far i got :)

Thanks in advance!

edwwVC.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "IIViewDeckController.h"

@class EDWWViewController;

@protocol EDWWViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>;
@optional
- (void)edwwVCDidFinish:(EDWWViewController *)edwwVC;
@end

@interface EDWWViewController : UIViewController <IIViewDeckControllerDelegate> {
__weak  id<EDWWViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
NSMutableArray *edwwPoints;
}

@property (weak) id<EDWWViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *theTableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic)     NSString *testString;
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)add:(id)sender;
@end
```

edwwVC.m:

```
#pragma mark - delegate method
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender {
testString = @"This is the test string!";
[delegate edwwVCDidFinish:self];
[self.viewDeckController closeRightViewAnimated:YES];
NSLog(@"Done pressed");
}
```

MainVC.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
edwwViewController = [[EDWWViewController alloc] init];
edwwViewController.delegate = self;
}  

- (void)edwwVCDidFinish:(EDWWViewController *)edwwVC {    
edwwLabel.text= edwwVC.testString;    
NSLog(@"delegate method called");
}
```

Comment: have you tried to put a breakpoint or log the delegate variable in you edWWVC done function to be sure it's not nil? (you might put it to nil somewhere in your code in the edwwVC.m

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the line ...

```
__weak  id<EDWWViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

From the .h and change the line...

```
[delegate edwwVCDidFinish:self];
```

to...

```
[self.delegate edwwVCDidFinish:self];
```

In the .m.

That should sort it.

The way you have it set up the ivar delegate is not the same as the property delegate (which is actually an ivar called _delegate) (thanks @Joris Kluivers, just adding for clarity).  They are pointing to different things.

If you add a breakpoint where you are calling the delegate method I think you'll find that delegate is nil.  Whereas _delegate (or self.delegate) is not nil.

::EDIT::

Ahh... just spotted the second bit too.

If you are setting up the edwwvc in storyboard then you should be alloc initing it too.

If you are segue-ing to the edwwvc then you should intercept the segue in mainVC.m like this...

```
- (void)prepareForSegue: //blah the rest of the name...
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"the name of your segue"])
    {
        EDWWViewController *controller = segue.destinationViewController;

        controller.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

This will take the controller that you are pushing to from the storyboard and set the delegate to it.

:: ANOTHER EDIT ::

If EDWWVC is inside a containerViewController then you can do this inside viewDidLoad in MainVC.m...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // other stuff...

    for (UIViewController *controller in self.childViewControllers) {
        if ([controller isKindOfClass:[EDWWViewController class]]) {
            EDWWViewController *edwwvc = (EDWWViewController*)controller;

            eddwvc.delegate = self;
        }
    }
}
```

You may find this code has to go in viewDidAppear or something but I think viewDidLoad shouldd work just fine.

You may actually be able to set the delegate property directly by using the storyboard to (but I'm not 100% certain on this).

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in the containerVC of both controllers.
Where i initialized the view controllers: the viewDidLoad of the containerVC m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

mainVC = (MainViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainVC"];
edwwVC = (EDWWViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EDWWVC"];
//THIS LINE WAS MISSING
edwwVC.delegate = mainVC;

self.centerController = mainVC;
self.rightController = edwwVC;    
}
```

BUT guys thanks for the help! :) Appreciate it got me in the right direction! :) THANKS! :)